# Ping method for many forms to async/await

Tags: vb.net

Have some mdi application. Within that application user has possibility to open some form to do some work. he can open multiple forms. Each time he opens new one he's asking to provide ip address in before little form, which value is passed to the form. Within each form i am trying to implement some engine to pmake ping given ip from time to time and show status of it on statusbar control. I decided to use `async/await` but i have problems, when user is putting the ip address and click ok button, then instead of FrmDrukujEtykiete shows up, error throws in my main application class. Can you support me how to make it works?

This is where error is showing up:

```
   Public Sub main()

        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Dim result As DialogResult
        Using frmL As New FrmLogin
            result = frmL.ShowDialog
        End Using

        If result = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim FrmMain As New FrmMain()
            Application.Run(FrmMain)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

an error is showing up on this line:

```
Application.Run(FrmMain)
```

that saying:

```
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

So step by step: User clicks button somwhere in mdi form then there is this code:

```
Dim pobierzIP As New FrmPobierzIP  'asking form to get ip
If pobierzIP.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
Dim drukujEtykiete As New FrmDrukujEtykiete(pobierzIP.Ip)  'targeted form
....
```

and this is where i am trying to implement async/await for my ping - something is wrong here that's aising above error:

```
Public Class FrmDrukujEtykiete

    Private Property IPAddress As String

    Sub New(ipaddress As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        PingPong()
        Me.IPAddress = ipaddress
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnWyjdz_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWyjdz.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub PingPong()
        While (True)
            Dim mytask As Task(Of Boolean)
            mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew(IsDestinationReachable(IPAddress))

            If Await mytask Then
                tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Green
                tsPingResultIcon.Text = "Reachable"
            Else
                tsPingResultIcon.BackColor = Color.Red
                tsPingResultIcon.Text = "Not reachable"
            End If

        End While
    End Sub

    Public Function IsDestinationReachable(ByVal hostnameOrAddress As String)
        Dim reachable As Boolean = False
        Try
            reachable = My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable AndAlso
                             My.Computer.Network.Ping(hostnameOrAddress)

        Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
        Catch genericNetworkException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException

            ' Fail silently and return false
        End Try
        Return reachable
    End Function


End Class
```

**EDIT: as per suggestion i make around try catch within Application.Run(FrmMain)
and this is the error i am getting:**

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: hostNameOrAddress

   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)

   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer)

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.Ping(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout)

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.Ping(String hostNameOrAddress)

   at FrmDrukujEtykiete.IsDestinationReachable(String hostnameOrAddress) in C:\Pliki\_Projekty\Tompson\Tompson\Tompson\FrmDrukujEtykiete.vb:line 37

   at FrmDrukujEtykiete.VB$StateMachine_70_PingPong.MoveNext() in C:\Pliki\_Projekty\Tompson\Tompson\Tompson\FrmDrukujEtykiete.vb:line 21

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
```

**EDIT3:**

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Action'.

   at FrmDrukujEtykiete.VB$StateMachine_70_PingPong.MoveNext() in C:\Pliki\_Projekty\sol\FrmDrukujEtykiete.vb:line 22

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
```

Comment: put a try/catch around Application.Run() to find out the exact error

Comment: i did - please check again main topic - EDIT section. Anyway the way i did it is it correct way or?

Comment: Try breaking out the reachable boolean into two bools (one for each test) set both initially to False and test/set each individually.  Then return the AndAlso of them.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that `hostNameOrAddress` cannot be null when calling `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send`.

This leads one to believe that it is not receiving the value passed into it.

Your `PingPong()` method is using the private property IPAddress to know what to ping. Your constructor, though, calls `PingPong()` *before* assigning a value to that property, so the IPAddress field is null when `PingPong()` calls out to `.Ping()`.

```
Sub New(ipaddress As String)
   InitializeComponent()
   PingPong()
   Me.IPAddress = ipaddress
End Sub
```

Swap the second and third lines of your constructor to assign the value to the property *before* you call `PingPong()`.

Comment: i did but now get other error on same line - see EDIT 3 in main topic

Comment: You're now getting into separate issues using async/await, unrelated to the original.  What does this new error message suggest?